# Checkbox in a table

Tags: ios, xcode, checkbox

I want to add a tick box (or if checkbox is a better name) in a table to every table row.
A small simple box to mark if a row is read or not. Just to remember.
And of course to be saved when I close the app.
And also to still be unchanged if the app is updated.

Is there an easy way to do that?
Is there any samples around?

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the following code I am using a code for making a todo list,  here I am using two `NSMutableArray` **itsToDoTitle** and **itsToDoChecked** to populate the table rows..I hope this will help you..

You can have the the **itsToDoTitle** and the **itsToDoChecked** Array in `NSUserDefaults` or you can write in some properties file so that you will have the same list again..

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {


    NSString *CellIdentifier = @"ToDoList";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) 
    {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault
                                       reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];

        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;
    }

    cell.textLabel.text = [itsToDoTitle objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.textLabel.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:14.0];
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;
    cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleBlue;


    BOOL checked =  [[itsToDoChecked objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] boolValue];
    UIImage *image = (checked) ? [UIImage imageNamed:@"checked.png"] : [UIImage imageNamed:@"unchecked.png"];

    UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    CGRect frame = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, image.size.width, image.size.height);
    button.frame = frame;   // match the button's size with the image size
    button.tag = indexPath.row;
    [button setBackgroundImage:image forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    // set the button's target to this table view controller so we can interpret touch events and map that to a NSIndexSet
    [button addTarget:self action:@selector(checkButtonTapped:event:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    cell.accessoryView = button;

    return cell;
}


- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView accessoryButtonTappedForRowWithIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{   

    BOOL checked = [[itsToDoChecked objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] boolValue];
    [itsToDoChecked removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    [itsToDoChecked insertObject:(checked) ? @"FALSE":@"TRUE" atIndex:indexPath.row];
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    UIButton *button = (UIButton *)cell.accessoryView;

    UIImage *newImage = (checked) ? [UIImage imageNamed:@"unchecked.png"] : [UIImage imageNamed:@"checked.png"];
    [button setBackgroundImage:newImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    UIBarButtonItem *backButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Save"
                                                                   style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(saveChecklist:)];
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = backButton;
    [backButton release];

}
```